# php regex split string with phone numbers to a few elements in the array

Tags: php, regex, phone-number, digits

How split string with phone numbers to a few elements in the array?

For example, we have string like this:
`"phone" => "+7 (343) 228-02-08 +7 (343) 203-209-3"` or `"phone" => "8 (800) 555-92-86 8 (499) 322-16-40 8 (812) 426-10-38"`

But we need to make it:

```
"phone" => [
     "0" => "+7 (343) 228-02-08",
     "1" => "+7 (343) 203-209-3",
]
```

and for another

```
"phone" => [
    "0" => "8 (800) 555-92-86 8",
    "1" => "8 (499) 322-16-40",
    "2" => "8 (812) 426-10-38",
]
```

I tried to find some ready-made solutions, but nothing could be found. Regular expressions - is too complicated for me ...

Comment: Do you have a pattern from where it could be broken to be phone number

Comment: What are other possible phone number strings your input may have?

Comment: @anubhava Just like I wrote. Thank for response!

Comment: try https://regex101.com/ to test your patterns. Also a course on regex is not a bad idea, you are gonna use them sooner or later as a developer, free course at https://regexone.com/

Comment: @sietse85 Yes, I ordered the book.

Comment: can you share the code, from where you get the phone no string. For ex: <input type="text" name="phone" value="" /> or something like that which you have used, If possible, please provide your full code.

Comment: @prateek-verma I'm writing a parser site. If there is no number, just an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `split` you can use matching using `preg_match_all` function using this regex:

```
/\+?\d\h*\(\d{3}\)\h*[\d-]+/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC0MFh/9)

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! I promise I will learn regular expressions.